# Looks through game reports in Battlefield 4

Tags: battlefield-4

Through Battlelog and bf4stats I can see game reports. With Battlelog it is very cumbersome to go through each report and see how many kills, death, points, etc etc. I'd like to see a list like in bf4stats. The problem with bf4stats is that it only seems to report 1 out of every 3 or 4 games!

Is there a better way?

Comment: IIRC bf4stats can only crawl the last 30 matches or so, so when you played 50 matches without visiting bf4stats, 20 matches are missing. Visiting bf4stats regularly should do the trick.

Comment: Hm, seems like what I said was true for bf3stats, but not for bf4stats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it worked with bf3stats was that upon updating your stats the site would crawl your recent battlereports from Battlelog, but only the last 20 are listed there. So to not miss any battlereports, you need to update at least every 20 games.

This text is shown in bf3stats when viewing reports:

> You can update your battle reports manually by clicking the UPDATE button.
>   We recommend to update your reports at last after every 20 rounds to not miss any reports.

This does not seem to be the case with BF4, there you can list more battle reports than the last twenty in Battlelog. Also bf4stats makes no comment on the update process for battlereports.

There is also a confusing [forum posts](http://forum.p-stats.com/threads/4003-BF4stats-com-Todo-list?highlight=reports) where reports are listed under "not done yet"

> - Add Battle Reports to bf4stats.com (might not be shown for some players, if they are not sharing them publicly)

and [one](http://forum.p-stats.com/threads/4631-Round-History?highlight=reports) where it says:

> I'm sorry we do not support battle reports at the moment.

My own profile only show 4 battle reports (there are many more), so it looks like an unfinished feature to me.